# Swift UITextField not editable in UIStackView

Tags: swift, uitextfield, uistackview

I am learning to develop an app. I am used a empty UIStackview which I will filled through the code. For this I created a Helper-Class (type327.swift). The Class return a Stackview which contains, three Sub-Stackview. One of this Subview is an Stackview with UITextfields. I want to modify the values on my Phone but it seems that the Textfields are not editable. What did I wrong or where is my logic failure?

Type327-Class:

```
    
    let unit: String?
    
    let labelVCurrentText: UILabel! = {
        let label = UILabel()
//        label.text = "Label 1"
//        label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: .regular)
//        label.numberOfLines = 1
//        label.backgroundColor = .clear
//        label.textAlignment = .left
//        //label.sizeToFit()
        return label
    }()
    let labelVNomText: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
//        label.text = "Label 1"
//        label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: .bold)
//        label.numberOfLines = 1
//        label.backgroundColor = .clear
//        label.textAlignment = .left
//        label.sizeToFit()
        return label
    }()
    let labelAimRelativText: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
//        label.text = "Label 1"
//        label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: .bold)
//        label.numberOfLines = 1
//        label.backgroundColor = .clear
//        label.textAlignment = .left
//        label.sizeToFit()
        return label
    }()
    let labelVMaxRelativeText: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
//        label.text = "Label 1"
//        label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: .bold)
//        label.numberOfLines = 1
//        label.backgroundColor = .clear
//        label.textAlignment = .left
//        label.sizeToFit()
        return label
    }()
    let labelVMinRelativeText: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
//        label.text = "Label 1"
//        label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: .bold)
//        label.numberOfLines = 1
//        label.backgroundColor = .clear
//        label.textAlignment = .left
//        label.sizeToFit()
        return label
    }()
    let labelVBtwRelativeText: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
//        label.text = "Label 1"
//        label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: .bold)
//        label.numberOfLines = 1
//        label.backgroundColor = .clear
//        label.textAlignment = .left
//        label.sizeToFit()
        return label
    }()
    let labelVAimAbsolutText: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
//        label.text = "Label 1"
//        label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: .bold)
//        label.numberOfLines = 1
//        label.backgroundColor = .clear
//        label.textAlignment = .left
//        label.sizeToFit()
        return label
    }()
    let labelVMaxAbsolutText: UILabel = {let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Label 1"
//        label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: .bold)
//        label.numberOfLines = 1
//        label.backgroundColor = .clear
//        label.textAlignment = .left
//        label.sizeToFit()
        return label}()
    let labelVMinAbsolutText: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
//        label.text = "Label 1"
//        label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: .bold)
//        label.numberOfLines = 1
//        label.backgroundColor = .clear
//        label.textAlignment = .left
//        label.sizeToFit()
        return label
    }()
    
    let labelVBtwAbsolutText: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        return label
    }()
    
    
    let txtVCurrentValue: UITextField = {
        let box = UITextField()
        box.keyboardType = .decimalPad
        box.isEditable
        return box
    }()
    
    let txtVNomValue: UITextField = {
        let box = UITextField()
        box.keyboardType = .decimalPad
        return box
    }()
    let txtAimRelativValue: UITextField = {
        let box = UITextField()
        box.keyboardType = .decimalPad
        return box
    }()
    let txtVMaxRelativeValue: UITextField = {
        let box = UITextField()
        box.keyboardType = .decimalPad
        return box
    }()
    let txtVMinRelativeValue: UITextField = {
        let box = UITextField()
        box.keyboardType = .decimalPad
        return box
    }()
    let txtVBtwRelativeValue: UITextField = {
        let box = UITextField()
        box.keyboardType = .decimalPad
        return box
    }()
    let txtVAimAbsolutValue: UITextField = {
        let box = UITextField()
        box.keyboardType = .decimalPad
        return box
    }()
    let txtVMaxAbsolutValue: UITextField = {
        let box = UITextField()
        box.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        box.keyboardType = .decimalPad
        return box
    }()
    let txtVMinAbsolutValue: UITextField = {
        let box = UITextField()
        box.keyboardType = .decimalPad
        return box
    }()
    let txtVBtwAbsolutValue: UITextField = {
        let box = UITextField()
        box.keyboardType = .decimalPad
        return box
    }()

    init(){
        labelVCurrentText.text = "∆ p@Vnom"
        labelVNomText.text = "Vnom"
        labelAimRelativText.text = "Target value rel."
        labelVMaxRelativeText.text = "VMax relativ"
        labelVMinRelativeText.text = "VMin relativ"
        labelVBtwRelativeText.text = "Vbtw realtiv"
        labelVAimAbsolutText.text = "Target value abs."
        labelVMaxAbsolutText.text = "VMax absolut"
        labelVMinAbsolutText.text = "VMin absolut"
        labelVBtwAbsolutText.text = "Vbtw absolut"
        
        txtVNomValue.text = String(0)
        txtVCurrentValue.text = String(0)
        txtAimRelativValue.text = String(0)
        txtVMaxRelativeValue.text = String(0)
        txtVMinRelativeValue.text = String(0)
        txtVBtwRelativeValue.text = String(0)
        txtVAimAbsolutValue.text = String(0)
        txtVMaxAbsolutValue.text = String(0)
        txtVMinAbsolutValue.text = String(0)
        txtVBtwAbsolutValue.text = String(0)
        unit = "m3/h"
    }
    
    
    lazy var viewText: UIStackView = {
        //MARK: - Textlabels for 327-View
        

        let labelText: [UILabel] = [labelVCurrentText, labelVNomText, labelAimRelativText, labelVMaxRelativeText, labelVMinRelativeText, labelVBtwRelativeText, labelVAimAbsolutText, labelVMaxAbsolutText, labelVMinAbsolutText, labelVBtwAbsolutText]
        for label in labelText {
            label.textAlignment = .left
        }
        let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: labelText)
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.spacing = 10

        return stackView
    }()
    
    lazy var viewUnit: UIStackView = {
        //MARK: - UnitLabels for 327-View
        let labelVCurrentUnit = UILabel()
        labelVCurrentUnit.text = "Pa"
        
        let labelVNomUnit = UILabel()
        labelVNomUnit.text = "m3/h"
        
        let labelAimRelativUnit = UILabel()
        labelAimRelativUnit.text = "%"
        
        let labelVMaxRelativeUnit = UILabel()
        labelVMaxRelativeUnit.text = "%"
        
        let labelVMinRelativeUnit = UILabel()
        labelVMinRelativeUnit.text = "%"
        
        let labelVBtwRelativeUnit = UILabel()
        labelVBtwRelativeUnit.text = "%"
        
        let labelVAimAbsolutUnit = UILabel()
        labelVAimAbsolutUnit.text = "m3/h"
        
        let labelVMaxAbsolutUnit = UILabel()
        labelVMaxAbsolutUnit.text = "m3/h"
        
        let labelVMinAbsolutUnit = UILabel()
        labelVMinAbsolutUnit.text = "m3/h"
        
        let labelVBtwAbsolutUnit = UILabel()
        labelVBtwAbsolutUnit.text = "m3/h"
        

        let labelUnit: [UILabel] = [labelVCurrentUnit, labelVNomUnit, labelAimRelativUnit, labelVMaxRelativeUnit, labelVMinRelativeUnit, labelVBtwRelativeUnit, labelVAimAbsolutUnit, labelVMaxAbsolutUnit, labelVMinAbsolutUnit, labelVBtwAbsolutUnit]
        for label in labelUnit {
            label.textAlignment = .left
        }
        let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: labelUnit)
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.spacing = 10

        return stackView
    }()
    
    lazy var viewValue: UIStackView = {
        //MARK: - Textlabels for 327-View
        
        let boxValue: [UITextField] = [txtVCurrentValue, txtVNomValue, txtAimRelativValue, txtVMaxRelativeValue, txtVMinRelativeValue, txtVBtwRelativeValue, txtVAimAbsolutValue, txtVMaxAbsolutValue, txtVMinAbsolutValue, txtVBtwAbsolutValue]
        
//        for label in labelValue {
//            label.textAlignment = .left
//            label.text = "n/a"
//        }
        let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: boxValue)
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.spacing = 10

        return stackView
    }()
    
    func setupStackViews() -> UIStackView {
        let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [viewText, viewValue, viewUnit])
        stackView.axis = .horizontal
        stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
        stackView.alignment = .fill
        stackView.spacing = 10
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        return stackView
    }
    
    
    
}
```

Call of created StackView in Controller:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        for label in viewLabels {
            label.text = "n/a"
        }
        viewState = .disconnected
        labelTitle.text = device?.name
        baseActuator = BaseActuator(modbus: mod)
        viewLabels = [labelProductnumber, labelActuatorIdent, labelSerialnumber, labelSoftwareVersion, labelActuatorType]
        AddLabelToQueue()
        lineChart.addSubview(lineChartView)
        lineChartView.centerInSuperview()
        lineChartView.width(to: lineChart)
        lineChartView.height(to: lineChart)
        setData()
        
        
        refreshControll.addTarget(self, action: #selector(DidRefreshView(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
        
        actuatorDataStackView.addSubview(type.setupStackViews())
        
    }
```

Can you help me and explain what did I wrong?

BR, freakontour

[Screenshot iPhone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pfy9R.jpg)

[Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWy8N.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note: very difficult to help when we can't use your code "as-is." It would be worth reviewing [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Second note: based on your code and the image of your storyboard, it looks a layout problem.

The red lines on the top and bottom of the gray view indicate that you are missing some constraints. Most likely, it does not have a Height constraint.

That's not necessarily a problem, but you are calling:

```
actuatorDataStackView.addSubview(type.setupStackViews())
```

without setting any constraints on the added stack view.

If you notice with your Screenshot of the app running, the gray background of the view in your storyboard is not showing. If you then use `Debug View Hierarchy`, you'll see that the gray view has a Height of Zero, and the  added stack view extends outside the bounds of the gray view.

You cannot interact with a UI element (such as a `UITextField`) if it is outside the bounds of its superview.

In storyboard, select the gray view and turn on `Clips to Bounds` (check the checkbox.

If you then run the app, you'll likely not even see your added stack view.

Assuming that turns out to be the case, try adding your stack view like this:

```
    let v = type.setupStackViews()
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    actuatorDataStackView.addSubview(v)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        v.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: actuatorDataStackView.topAnchor),
        v.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: actuatorDataStackView.leadingAnchor),
        v.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: actuatorDataStackView.trailingAnchor),
        v.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: actuatorDataStackView.bottomAnchor),
    ])
```

That will cause the gray view to grow to the size of the added stack view.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am new in Xcode/ Swift to develop an app and often there are some tricky points where I am have troubles. Also thank you for your detailed explanation, now it is more clear and I get a better understanding of the constraints.